# Change default cache location of android

Tags: android

I need to change the cache location of android to sdcard programmatically.
can anyone suggest a direction.

thank you..

Answer (score 1):

To get the path of the externa storage directory you can use

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

from ter go to your folder.

Comment: Doesn't that only retrieve a location?  It sounds like he wants to change it.

Comment: thanks for the reply. and because of health reasons I arrived late. I actually need to change my default cache location to the path that you have provided.